# How to clean up old connections before mapping a new drive?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, network-share

I have scripts on Windows Server 2008r2 that access specific resources on other server systems using limited credentials.  If a person or other script has also accessed that system from this server with different credentials and didn't log out, scripts fail with `Error 1219 "The network folder specified is currently mapped using a different user name and password"`

How to ensure that my script deletes all connections to this specific machine before trying to map a new drive?

```
C:\> net use //server /d
```

doesn't work on its own. I can follow it up with `net use` and see that a drive is still shared:

```
C:\> net use \\server /d
\\server was deleted successfully.


C:\> net use
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Disconnected           \\server\somedrive       Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

The disconnected drive will still cause the same `Error 1219`.

Can anyone suggest a more elegant solution than deleting an exhaustive list of all shares that exists on that machine?

```
net use \\server\share1 /d
net use \\server\share2 /d
net use \\server\share3 /d
etc...
```

Also

```
net use \\server\* /d
```

fails with "connection not found".

Answer (score 1):

The command is:

**net use /d * /y**

Comment: I'm trying to delete all connections one specific \\server.  I think net use /d * /y will delete all connections to all servers, right?

Comment: Yes it will. I didn't pick that up in your question. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work.

```
C:\Users\User>net use /d * /y
Tiene estas conexiones remotas:

    S:              \\server.server.org@SSL\remote.php\webdav
Si continúa, se cancelarán las conexiones.

Se ha completado el comando correctamente.

C:\Users\User>net use /persistent:no S: "https://server.server.org/remote.php/webdav"
Se ha completado el comando correctamente.
```

(NOTICE I'M NOT ASKED FOR PASSWORD)

```
C:\Users\User>net use /d * /y
Tiene estas conexiones remotas:

    S:              \\server.server.org@SSL\remote.php\webdav
Si continúa, se cancelarán las conexiones.

Se ha completado el comando correctamente.


C:\Users\User>net use /persistent:no S: "https://server.server.org/remote.php/webdav"  /user:differentuser
Error de sistema 1219.

Las conexiones múltiples para un servidor o recurso compartido compatible por el mismo usuario, usando más de un nombre de usuario, no están permitidas. Desconecte todas las conexiones anteriores al servidor o recursos compartido e inténtelo de nuevo.
```